I can't run the python module
First, I apologize for my poor English and thank you for any help
I found the im2dhisteq module from GitHub and installed it with pip
Module link on GitHub :
https://github.com/Mamdasn/im2dhisteq
but it is not recognized when running in the command line.

C:\Windows\system32>im2dhisteq --input 'a.jpg' --output 'b.jpg' --w 6

'im2dhisteq' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Then I went to the python script folder and found it but it has no format

What should I do to use this module in the command line?
pip install im2dhisteq
im2dhisteq --input 'a.jpg' --output 'b.jpg' --w 6

This is not technically a programming question, but: this module installs an executable that you can use from the command line, but the directory where it is is not in your PATH. Try python -m im2dhisteq ... which explicitly invokes it via Python. (The instructions here are not great, among other things they seem to assume you're using Linux or similar, while you're using Windows.)

Please refer to the Github link. This method is suggested for implementation

this project docs assume that you are in its folder. If you want to be able to access it from everywhere, you have to add its location to system path.
Here is a tutorial on how to do it
